# Kendo Grid - Conditional ClientTemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following client template in a Kendo grid:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate("<input id='#=data.ID#' type='checkbox' onclick='chkEntry(this)' />")
```

etc...

That works fine. I want instead to only show that input if data.CandidateCode is equal to 'CO1'.

This is one of my attempts:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ID).ClientTemplate("#if (# #=data.CandidateCode# # == 'CO1') {#<input id='#=data.ID#' type='checkbox' onclick= chkEntry(this)' /> #}#")
```

It is my understanding that one may use hashtag (#) to indicate arbitrary javascript, as well as for literals and data values. Am I on the right track here? No matter how I try this syntax, I get an 'Uncaught Error: Invalid template' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the [hash syntax](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) can be tricky. Once you start js with '#" you don't need to further escape variables. When you are in the markup like `<input>` you do. So try this without the comment lines:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID)
                     // Inside code no need to hashtag CandidateCode
    .ClientTemplate("# if (CandidateCode == 'CO1') { #" +                           " 
                     // Inside markup you do need hashtag
                    "<input id='#=ID#' type='checkbox' onclick='chkEntry(this)' />" +
                    "#}#")
```